# YouTube iframe api is resizing my embedded videos with the wrong size

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video into a page on my site.  I'm using exactly the code specified in https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference:

```
<div id='player'></div>"
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
       height: '940',
       width: '528',
       videoId: 'the_embed_code'
    });
  }
</script>
```

This successfully embeds a player for the video in my page, at the appropriate place.  However, it has added some style parameters that resize the iframe containing the player to 300px by 150px.  The iframe generated by the above code looks like this:

```
<iframe id="player" class="vjs-paused" width="940" height="528" 
    style="width: 300px; height: 150px;" frameborder="0" 
    allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/the_embed_code?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.domain.com">
</iframe>
```

I have no idea where these parameters are coming from; it happens consistently on (Mac) Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and even iPad Safari and Chrome.  The onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function is getting called, at what seems to be an appropriate time.  Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 0):

Problem (mostly) solved -- I seem to have some bits of jQuery code that don't play completely nicely with each other.  Once I changed the ID of the div containing the player to something other than 'player', things started working properly.  I'm not sure what the problem really is (i.e., who/what the culprit is), but at least there's a trivial workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem: wrong video embed sizing. I noticed that my media embed said " media_embed" so I changed that to "player" and voila it works great. Thanks for your help on this, it was so great to solve this problem!

Comment: Yay! (Now I add 10 more characters to make SO happy.)